# Geographic limit to overlay analysis in geoprocessing service

Tags: python, arcgis-server, geoprocessing, rest

**Function:**
I've created a geoprocessing service that serves a toolbox containing a custom python tool.  This python tool selects a polygon and buffers it by 1 mile.  This buffer is then used to intersect with another polygon layer to produce a list of features in the overlay.  Pretty simple.

**Environment:**
The same geoprocessing service is re-created four times [three Oracle environments and four GIS web applications].

**Error:**
In three of four gp services, when this tool is used at a REST endpoint --*and when the overlays is in a specific geographic region* [roughly 250 sq. miles]-- this error is produced: “Invalid Topology [Cannot read input cache.] Failed to execute (Intersect). Failed to execute (ToolCustomIntersect)”

**Fix:**
I've debugged a bazillion ways and have come up with one solution: re-create the  GP service with a different name (as improbable a fix as this seems).

**What just happened!?!**
The only pattern that I've deduced through various tests is that names of GP services containing a high redundancy of letters in a complete pathname or the length of the name resulted in this error.

**The kicker** is when I run the same tool in AC on the AGS server it works.  Meaning I'm not utilizing the gp service or the REST endpoint.  No topology or cache error.  So, there is something about the GP service that is producing a geographic limitation to an overlay tool.

Quirk?  Or real issue.  I'd love your ideas and comments.